# Why I can't call flatMap on Option[List]

Tags: scala, collections

```
println(List(List(1,2,3)).flatMap(identity))
```

= List(1,2,3)

```
println(Iterable(List(1,2,3)).flatMap(identity))
```

same result

```
println(Option(List(1,2,3)).flatMap(identity))

    Error:(8, 39) type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int] => List[Int]
 required: List[Int] => Option[?]
  println(Option(List(1,2,3)).flatMap(identity))
                                      ^
                                                  ^
```

I thought there is a option2iterable implicit conversion so Options should behave the same as Iterable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an implicit defined in the `Option` companion:

```
/** An implicit conversion that converts an option to an iterable value
 */
implicit def option2Iterable[A](xo: Option[A]): Iterable[A] = xo.toList
```

But it is not applied in this situation because `Option` has its own `flatMap` method.

```
def flatMap[B](f: A => Option[B]): Option[B]
```

You can coerce the `Option` to `Iterable` to force the implicit to apply:

```
scala> (Option(List(1, 2, 3)): Iterable[List[Int]]).flatMap(identity)
res0: Iterable[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Or just call `.toIterable`:

```
scala> Option(List(1, 2, 3)).toIterable.flatMap(identity)
res1: Iterable[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, what do you expect the output of that `flatMap` be? You can't have `Option(1,2,3)`, can you? You can only have `Option` of one thing, and for that reason, a function you pass to `.flatMap` must return an `Option`, not just any `Iterable`, so that you can guarantee that there is at most one thing inside of it.